# How to add a function to Xamarin Forms WebView long-press event?

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I'm relatively new to Xamarin.Forms. I want to trigger a function for a long-press gesture event on a link in the WebView, such as popping up a context menu. The default WebView does not respond to the built-in gesture recognizer as I understood from [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397090/xamarin-forms-handle-clicked-event-on-webview)
It does seem like XLabs' HybridWebView allows you to implement a click event. Is it possible to use the same method to implement a gesture recognizer event? If so, can I possibly get a link from the event's source? I'd appreciate it if anyone could show me an example.

Thank you!