# How to send webview object from PCL to any other platform (UWP, Android, iOS)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, xamarin.uwp

Is that possible to pass the webview object from PCL (shared folder) to other platform like UWP, Android, iOS?

**Code in PCL MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var browser = new WebView
    {
        Source = "http://google.com"
    }

    Content = browser;
}
```

**Code in UWP MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    LoadApplication(new PCL.App());
}
```

From the codes above, how to take the webview object declared in PCL to send to UWP, and how UWP receive the webview object send by PCL?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by passing web view?

Comment: @KK get the event handler, or any property that the single webview provided and do some changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397090/xamarin-forms-handle-clicked-event-on-webview refer link this might help