# WebView GestureRecognition not working in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a webview When this webview is tapped I need to make visible of a button the problem Is Gesture recognition is not working

my Xaml

```
   <customRenderer:CustomWebView Uri="{Binding SelectedJournal.Uri}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  x:Name="CustomWebView" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,50,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"  >
            <customRenderer:CustomWebView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped2" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" ></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </customRenderer:CustomWebView.GestureRecognizers>
        </customRenderer:CustomWebView>

        <customRenderer:NavigationImageButton ItemTapped="FullScreenOnTapped" Source="full.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,-1,-1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" x:Name="FullScreenBtn" IsVisible="False" >
```

In the code behind i called like this

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FullScreenBtn.IsVisible = true;
    }
```

This should work but this is not working

also my custom rendering web view class

```
  public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomWebView, string>(p => p.Uri, default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

How to Achive this

Comment: Why exactly would you do this?

Comment: @G.hakim I have a button I used this webview to show a pdf when the content is touch I need to pop up a button that's my purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the gesture recognizer on your webview, you can use the 'Focused' event of your view to display your button. You can do something like this:

```
var wb = new WebView
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Source = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320611/webview-gesturerecognition-not-working-in-xamarin-forms",
};

wb.Focused += (s, e) =>
{
   //Handle your logic here!
   wb.Unfocus();
 };
```

Here, Unfocus() is used if you wish to implement your logic everytime the webview is tapped.

Comment: Good one! Thanks for this.

Comment: I'm not getting the focused event triggered on iOS (15.0) when tapping on a WebView. Works on Android.

Answer (score 0):

A `WebView` is used in my application to display formatted text. Tapping the text should open an editor to modify the text. The suggested `Focused` event works on Android but not iOS (as of iOS 15.0 simulator at least). I found the solution in the comments for https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/42/42596/bug.html#c4. Adding an empty label to the xaml as a transparent overlay of the `WebView` registers the tap event and enables the gesture recogniser.

```
<Grid HeightRequest="132">
    <WebView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
             Source="{Binding FormattedDescription, Converter={tr:StringToWebViewSourceConverter}}"
             HeightRequest="132"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text=""
           HeightRequest="132" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding EditDescriptionCommand}"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```