# Click Object on Web Page in Xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin

I wan to click button which created in web page.
I added following code to the my project but it did execute, string always null.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wbWeb.Source = "https://www.facebook.com";
    }

    private async void btnBrowser_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
       string str = wbWeb.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('loginbutton').click();");
      //str is null
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h3KRhkjwv8&t=8s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397090/xamarin-forms-handle-clicked-event-on-webview Check this answer